# Finding Center of Mass for Humanoid Robot

Tags: mobile-robot, inverse-kinematics, humanoid, balance

I've been working on Humanoid Robot, and I face the problem of finding the Center of Mass of the Robot which will help in balancing the biped. Although COM has a very simple definition, I'm unable to find a simple solution to my problem.

My view: I have already solved the Forward and Inverse Kinematics of the Robot with Torso as the base frame. So, if I can find the position(and orientation) of each joint in the base frame, I can average all of them to get the COM. Is this approach reasonable? Will it produce the correct COM?

Can anyone offer any series of steps that I can follow to find the COM of the biped? Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Use the forward kinematics to calculate the COM of each link in the frame of interest (torso for you). Calculate the humanoid COM using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_body_dynamics#Mass_properties

Comment: Good answer @hauptmech.  Please make it a real answer so we can up-vote it!  Comments are for clarifications to questions and answers.

Comment: @Bilal Wasim - Do you know the individual center of masses of all the links in the humanoid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  As @hauptmech mentioned, you can use your forward kinematics to get the center of mass of each link in the base frame.  Then you can simply compute the *weighted* average of the masses and positions to get the overall center of mass.

In other words:

$$
M = \sum_{i=0}^n m_i
$$
$$
\mathbf{P}_i^0 = pos( \mathbf{T}_i^0(\mathbf{q}) \mathbf{T}_{i_m}^i)
$$
$$
\mathbf{COM}^0 = \frac{1}{M} \sum_{i=0}^n m_i \mathbf{P}_i^0
$$

Where:

- $m_i$ = mass of link $i$
- $M$ = total mass
- $\mathbf{q}$ = vector of joint angles
- $\mathbf{T}_i^0$ = Transform from base frame $0$ to link $i$.  (The forward kinematics which is a function of $\mathbf{q}$).
- $\mathbf{T}_{i_m}^i$ = Transform from the link $i$ frame to it's center of mass.
- $pos()$ = function to extract position vector from full transform.
- $\mathbf{P}_i^0$ = position of mass of link $i$ in base frame $0$.
- $\mathbf{COM}^0$ = center of mass of system in base frame $0$.